# Removing the grey overlay/backdrop from $mdSidenav

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design

I use some components from **Angular Material** in my project, and I have some issues with removing the grey overlay/backdrop for the service `$mdSidenav`, because I don't see where I can configure it.

As I don't want to hack the core code in Angular material, I am wondering what's the best way of removing the grey overlay/backdrop when the side nav panel slides in (active). Could someone point me to where I can configure or override the grey overlay? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS:

```
md-backdrop.md-sidenav-backdrop{
    display:none
}
```

**Warning:** This could break user functionality.

Comment: do not use this since the directive listens to click event in   element with class md-sidenav-backdrop in order to close the sidenav bar

Comment: Whilst the documentation doesn't seem to explicitly mention `md-disable-backdrop`, it's definitely the proper solution

Comment: The docs do mention it, right in the [Attributes table](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSidenav#attributes). This type of heavy-handed CSS can actually break user functionality. It isn't the best approach. Maybe `visibility: hidden;` or `opacity: 0;` as a last resort, but Dor Cohen's solution is better.

Comment: md-disable-backdrop is definitely better

Answer (score 12):

You can use the built-in Angular Material attribute directive `md-disable-backdrop`. It accepts a boolean value and, when present in the markup, the sidenav will not show a backdrop.

```
<md-sidenav md-disable-backdrop>
</md-sidenav>
```